# Should I add ' before integers when making an ENUM field

Tags: php, laravel, enums, migration, laravel-migrations

I want to create a Migration and this Migration has a field named `is_active` which takes one of **1** or **0** values.

So I tried:

```
$table->enum('is_active', ['0', '1']);
```

But I wonder, if this alright or I should write it this way:

```
$table->enum('is_active', [0, 1]);
```

So which one is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in the PHP [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) that `string '0',int 0,float 0.0` are considered as `false` and `int 1,string '1',float 1.0` are considered as `true`

Although in your case you can use `$table->boolean('is_active');` instead of `enum`